# Issue with Configurable Images

Tags: product-images, configurable-swatches, magento2.3.5-p1

> If i didn't put an image in a child product that is linked to a
> configurable that it would only show the image in the parent product,
> it is  showing the placeholder. How do I stop this from happening?

[image]